# cannot draw proper position on transformed SVG

Tags: svg

I know I can free draw on a non scaled SVG group. But after I scaled the group, the drawing position is not following my mouse position properly.

example if I zoom out my svg group 1.3 times bigger, see below
[image]

I have a transformed matrix applied to the group.

my question is how to solve the position on the scaled group to follow my mouse position?

Regards,
JX

Comment: Can you be more explicit. I don't understand your problem. And why do you define the matrix both in "style" and "transform"?

Comment: so it can work for different browsers